# How to translate an OID to a JCE algorithm name?

Tags: java, cryptography, jce, oid

I am looking for a library that can take a oid such as `1.2.840.10040.4.3` and translate it to its standard name (in this case `SHA1withDSA`)

Using `org.cesecore.certificates.util.AlgorithmTools`, I am able to achieve some of the required functionality, but it is very limited.

This is the current code:

```
String signatureAlgorithmName = AlgorithmTools.getAlgorithmNameFromOID(oid);
```

**Note:**

The standard names can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Signature)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an online database of OID's at [oid-info.com](http://www.oid-info.com/) that you can use.

As you can see the OID database is huge. Besides that, due to companies defining their own OID's under their base OID, many OID's are actually unknown.

The `AlgorithmTools` class has simply defined a list of OID's for signature algorithms, it doesn't attempt to dynamically find out which algorithms are available by using an OID as alias.

Note that some OID's are used for multiple classes. For instance, you can have an RSA `Cipher`, `KeyFactory` and `KeyPairGenerator`.

You can however find out which OID's are available for the currently installed providers:

```
package nl.owlstead.stackoverflow;

import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.Provider.Service;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class GetOIDToAlgorithmNameMapping {
    private static final Pattern KEY_TYPE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^(\\w+)[.].*$");
    private static final Pattern KEY_ALIAS_TYPE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^Alg[.]Alias[.](\\w+).*$");
    private static final Pattern KEY_OID_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(".*?(\\d+(?:[.]\\d+){3,})$");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Provider[] provs = Security.getProviders();

        for (Provider prov : provs) {
            System.out.printf("%n >>> Provider: %s <<< %n%n", prov.getName());

            SortedSet<String> typeAndOID = getTypeAndOIDStrings(prov);

            for (String entry : typeAndOID) {
                String[] typeAndOIDArray = entry.split("-");
                String type = typeAndOIDArray[0];
                String oid = typeAndOIDArray[1];
                Service service = prov.getService(type, oid);
                String algo = service.getAlgorithm();
                System.out.printf("Type: %s, OID: %s, algo: %s%n", type, oid, algo);
            }
        }
    }

    private static SortedSet<String> getTypeAndOIDStrings(Provider prov) {
        SortedSet<String> typeAndOID = new TreeSet<>();

        Set<Object> keys = prov.keySet();
        for (Object key : keys) {
            String keyString = key.toString();
            Matcher oidMatcher = KEY_OID_PATTERN.matcher(keyString);
            if (oidMatcher.matches()) {
                // get OID from matched keyString
                String oid = oidMatcher.group(1);

                // determine type
                String type;
                Matcher aliasTypeMatcher = KEY_ALIAS_TYPE_PATTERN.matcher(keyString);
                if (aliasTypeMatcher.matches()) {
                    type = aliasTypeMatcher.group(1);
                } else {
                    Matcher typeMatcher = KEY_TYPE_PATTERN.matcher(keyString);
                    typeMatcher.matches();
                    type = typeMatcher.group(1);
                }

                // algorithm parameters are not algorithms, so skip them
                if (type.equals("AlgorithmParameters")) {
                    continue;
                }

                // auto-removes dupes
                typeAndOID.add(type + "-" + oid);
            }
        }
        return typeAndOID;
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
 >>> Provider: SUN <<< 

Type: KeyFactory, OID: 1.2.840.10040.4.1, algo: DSA
Type: KeyFactory, OID: 1.3.14.3.2.12, algo: DSA
Type: KeyPairGenerator, OID: 1.2.840.10040.4.1, algo: DSA
Type: KeyPairGenerator, OID: 1.3.14.3.2.12, algo: DSA
Type: MessageDigest, OID: 1.3.14.3.2.26, algo: SHA
Type: MessageDigest, OID: 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1, algo: SHA-256
Type: MessageDigest, OID: 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.2, algo: SHA-384
Type: MessageDigest, OID: 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.3, algo: SHA-512
Type: MessageDigest, OID: 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.4, algo: SHA-224
Type: Signature, OID: 1.2.840.10040.4.3, algo: SHA1withDSA
Type: Signature, OID: 1.3.14.3.2.13, algo: SHA1withDSA
Type: Signature, OID: 1.3.14.3.2.27, algo: SHA1withDSA
Type: Signature, OID: 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.3.1, algo: SHA224withDSA
Type: Signature, OID: 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.3.2, algo: SHA256withDSA

 >>> Provider: SunRsaSign <<< 

Type: KeyFactory, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.1, algo: RSA
Type: KeyPairGenerator, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.1, algo: RSA
Type: Signature, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11, algo: SHA256withRSA
Type: Signature, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.12, algo: SHA384withRSA
Type: Signature, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.13, algo: SHA512withRSA
Type: Signature, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.14, algo: SHA224withRSA
Type: Signature, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.2, algo: MD2withRSA
Type: Signature, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.4, algo: MD5withRSA
Type: Signature, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5, algo: SHA1withRSA
Type: Signature, OID: 1.3.14.3.2.29, algo: SHA1withRSA

 >>> Provider: SunEC <<< 

Type: Signature, OID: 1.2.840.10045.4.1, algo: SHA1withECDSA
Type: Signature, OID: 1.2.840.10045.4.3.1, algo: SHA224withECDSA
Type: Signature, OID: 1.2.840.10045.4.3.2, algo: SHA256withECDSA
Type: Signature, OID: 1.2.840.10045.4.3.3, algo: SHA384withECDSA
Type: Signature, OID: 1.2.840.10045.4.3.4, algo: SHA512withECDSA

 >>> Provider: SunJSSE <<< 

Type: KeyFactory, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.1, algo: RSA
Type: KeyPairGenerator, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.1, algo: RSA
Type: Signature, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.2, algo: MD2withRSA
Type: Signature, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.4, algo: MD5withRSA
Type: Signature, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5, algo: SHA1withRSA
Type: Signature, OID: 1.3.14.3.2.29, algo: SHA1withRSA

 >>> Provider: SunJCE <<< 

Type: AlgorithmParameterGenerator, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.3.1, algo: DiffieHellman
Type: Cipher, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.1, algo: PBEWithSHA1AndRC4_128
Type: Cipher, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.2, algo: PBEWithSHA1AndRC4_40
Type: Cipher, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.3, algo: PBEWithSHA1AndDESede
Type: Cipher, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.5, algo: PBEWithSHA1AndRC2_128
Type: Cipher, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.6, algo: PBEWithSHA1AndRC2_40
Type: Cipher, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.5.3, algo: PBEWithMD5AndDES
Type: Cipher, OID: 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.1, algo: AES_128/ECB/NoPadding
Type: Cipher, OID: 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.2, algo: AES_128/CBC/NoPadding
Type: Cipher, OID: 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.21, algo: AES_192/ECB/NoPadding
Type: Cipher, OID: 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.22, algo: AES_192/CBC/NoPadding
Type: Cipher, OID: 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.23, algo: AES_192/OFB/NoPadding
Type: Cipher, OID: 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.24, algo: AES_192/CFB/NoPadding
Type: Cipher, OID: 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.25, algo: AESWrap_192
Type: Cipher, OID: 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.26, algo: AES_192/GCM/NoPadding
Type: Cipher, OID: 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.3, algo: AES_128/OFB/NoPadding
Type: Cipher, OID: 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.4, algo: AES_128/CFB/NoPadding
Type: Cipher, OID: 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.41, algo: AES_256/ECB/NoPadding
Type: Cipher, OID: 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.42, algo: AES_256/CBC/NoPadding
Type: Cipher, OID: 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.43, algo: AES_256/OFB/NoPadding
Type: Cipher, OID: 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.44, algo: AES_256/CFB/NoPadding
Type: Cipher, OID: 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.45, algo: AESWrap_256
Type: Cipher, OID: 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.46, algo: AES_256/GCM/NoPadding
Type: Cipher, OID: 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.5, algo: AESWrap_128
Type: Cipher, OID: 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.6, algo: AES_128/GCM/NoPadding
Type: KeyAgreement, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.3.1, algo: DiffieHellman
Type: KeyFactory, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.3.1, algo: DiffieHellman
Type: KeyGenerator, OID: 1.2.840.113549.2.10, algo: HmacSHA384
Type: KeyGenerator, OID: 1.2.840.113549.2.11, algo: HmacSHA512
Type: KeyGenerator, OID: 1.2.840.113549.2.7, algo: HmacSHA1
Type: KeyGenerator, OID: 1.2.840.113549.2.8, algo: HmacSHA224
Type: KeyGenerator, OID: 1.2.840.113549.2.9, algo: HmacSHA256
Type: KeyPairGenerator, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.3.1, algo: DiffieHellman
Type: Mac, OID: 1.2.840.113549.2.10, algo: HmacSHA384
Type: Mac, OID: 1.2.840.113549.2.11, algo: HmacSHA512
Type: Mac, OID: 1.2.840.113549.2.7, algo: HmacSHA1
Type: Mac, OID: 1.2.840.113549.2.8, algo: HmacSHA224
Type: Mac, OID: 1.2.840.113549.2.9, algo: HmacSHA256
Type: SecretKeyFactory, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.1, algo: PBEWithSHA1AndRC4_128
Type: SecretKeyFactory, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.2, algo: PBEWithSHA1AndRC4_40
Type: SecretKeyFactory, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.3, algo: PBEWithSHA1AndDESede
Type: SecretKeyFactory, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.5, algo: PBEWithSHA1AndRC2_128
Type: SecretKeyFactory, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.6, algo: PBEWithSHA1AndRC2_40
Type: SecretKeyFactory, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.5.12, algo: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1
Type: SecretKeyFactory, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.5.3, algo: PBEWithMD5AndDES

 >>> Provider: SunJGSS <<< 

Type: GssApiMechanism, OID: 1.2.840.113554.1.2.2, algo: 1.2.840.113554.1.2.2
Type: GssApiMechanism, OID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.2, algo: 1.3.6.1.5.5.2

 >>> Provider: SunSASL <<< 


 >>> Provider: XMLDSig <<< 


 >>> Provider: SunPCSC <<< 


 >>> Provider: SunMSCAPI <<< 

Type: Signature, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11, algo: SHA256withRSA
Type: Signature, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.12, algo: SHA384withRSA
Type: Signature, OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.13, algo: SHA512withRSA
```